# Regex - matching a substring of text to a substring of a pattern

Tags: python, regex, string-matching, fuzzy-search

So I'm in a counter-intuitive situation, and I wanted to get some advice.
Mostly I'm just doing some string matching, using extracted string as the patterns for my regular expression. While generally I can do this pretty well overall with a fuzzy regex search, on occasion I run into this situation:

Let's say I've extracted the following pattern from some data (Python regex package).

```
pattern = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
```

Now, I need to have it match a string that could look like either of these, though mostly the first one.

```
string = 'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy'
string2 = 'and then a quick brown fox jumps onto the cat'
```

Because of the beginning and trailing characters, obviously I won't get a match if I try and do something like what I've been doing, which currently looks something like this:

```
if re.search("("+pattern+"){e<=2}", string):
    print(True)
```

Unfortunately the error count is not consistent and there could be many characters leading and/or ending the pattern. Given I don't know *a priori* if I'll run into this problem, is there anything I could do to get a match if a sufficient substring of the pattern matches it? I looked at Levenshtein distance to account for this, but it requires setting some threshold that seems super sensitive to the length of the strings to match (after normalizing by length), and so it just ends up being a toss up on whether or not I get a match when I want it to. Are there any other options out there or better ways of normalizing results?

Also, one thing that I can't do is to just always take the best match because sometimes the proper entry doesn't actually appear in the text I'm checking.

Anything I've missed in the regex package that could help out with this?

Comment: Have you checked out `nltk`? It sounds like you want to compare word stem frequencies (with perhaps weights based on overall word frequency) in your strings and return the best matches. I think `nltk` has support for that. http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-iv-stemming-and-lemmatization

Comment: What is *a sufficient substring of the pattern*? That is the value you usually have to calculate yourself and use together with the Levenstein distance function.

Comment: What about with words interleaved such as `string='quick blah brown blah fox blah blog jumps blow over blech the crazy'`?

Answer (score 0):

Ouf, took me quite some time to come with this (I'm not a python developer), but this should do the trick:

```
import re

sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
string = 'quick brown fox jumps over the lazy'
string2 = 'and then a quick brown fox jumps onto the cat'
count1 = 0
count2 = 0


pattern = re.sub(
    '(\w+\s*)',
    '\\1|',
    sentence
)

pattern ="(?:(?!" + pattern.rstrip("|") + ").|" + re.sub(
    '(\w+\s*)',
    '(\\1){0,1}',
    sentence
) + ")+"

results = re.match(
    pattern,
    string
)

total = len(results.groups())

for index in range(1, total):

    if results.group(index):
        count1 = count1 + 1

results = re.match(
    pattern,
    string2
)

for index in range(1, total):

    if results.group(index):
        count2 = count2 + 1

message = 'The following string:"' + string + '" matched ' + str(count1) + ' time and the following string:"' + string + '" matched ' + str(count2) + ' time.'
```

Tested here: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

[image]